# Mixing Queue Ops with regular Python for data loading

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on sequence learning for audio and need to load my audio data. Currently I rely on `tf.decode_csv` to load pairs of filenames and labels into a Tensorflow Queue. However, I then would like to actually read the file and process it with other Python libs. Yet, the CSV decoder / dequeuing operations always return tensor ops making interoperability with other Python libs impossible. Any ideas on how to mix TF's streaming operations with external libs?

```
file_path = tf.train.string_input_producer([csv_path])
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, csv_content = reader.read(file_path)

decode_op = tf.decode_csv(csv_content, record_defaults=[[""], [0]])
enqueue_ops.append(examples_queue.enqueue(decode_op))

tf.train.queue_runner.add_queue_runner(
   tf.train.queue_runner.QueueRunner(examples_queue, enqueue_ops)) 
...
sound_path, label_index = examples_queue.dequeue() <--- !!!!
data = read_wav(sound_path)
```

The `sound_path` is a tensor of dtype `string` but I am unable to actually cast/convert it into a Python string for compatibility with the `read_wav` lib.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your `read_wav` function expects a filename (string) as argument, and returns a numpy array of float values (the decoded file).

The computation of `read_wav` takes place outside of the tensorflow graph, in python. Instead of calling `sess.run(sound_path)`, which would create a lot of runs (one for each filename), you can use [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/script_ops.html#py_func) to encapsulate Python code in a TensorFlow wrapper. You need to specify the types of the outputs to `tf.py_func`.

```
sound_path, label_index = examples_queue.dequeue()
data = tf.py_func(your_function, [sound_path], [tf.float32])
```

Your function needs to take a numpy array as input and returns numpy arrays.

```
def your_function(sound_path):
    sound_path = sound_path[0]
    data = read_wav(sound_path)  # should be a numpy array
    return data
```

Comment: I didn't know `tf.py_func` :O Excellent answer, +1

Comment: Yeah it's the easiest way to add custom operations but it will be computed only on CPU (so the data needs to be transferred from GPU if it was on it)

Comment: Even though I wrapped my function as `tf.py_func` the input argument is still a CSVDecode Tensor. How can "cast" into a string? At the time of the operation/function definition no session has been initiated yet. In other words, the input argument is not a numpy data type.

Comment: This is what tf.py_func will do for you. It will take a string tensor as input and transform it to a numpy array, which is fed to your function. Similarly, the numpy output of your function is transformed into a tensor, without using a session.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I got it working. One last thing? Can the input arguments be of different types? `read_wav(string: path, bool: isNormalized)` etc?

Comment: Yes it will work as long as they are all Tensors. It is the job of the python function to handle these different jobs, so no problem

Answer (score 0):

To extract the content of a tensor, you have to "run it" into a session.

`sound_path_value = sess.run(sound_path)`

Comment: What I don't understand is why it is not already run by the time the above call is made. My setup is as follows:


Define DataLoader --> Set as Input to conv layer --> add model to optimizer --> `sess.run(optimizer)`


Now, the DataLoader is the first thing that is defined. If you use pure tensor operations they act as placeholders until the `sess.run` is evaluated in the main training loop and everything is fine. 

In other words the data loader is defined before any model, optimizer or session is instantiated.